# How to understand the result returned by "nm" command

Tags: libraries, function, nm

I used `nm` command to inspect the function names in a .so library.
And the result I got is like this:

```
00009634 T _Z24ICTCLAS_ParagraphProcessPKciPc9eCodeTypeb
00009764 T _Z25ICTCLAS_ParagraphProcessAPKciRi9eCodeTypeb
00009b24 T _Z26ICTCLAS_ParagraphProcessAWPKcP17tagICTCLAS_Result9eCodeTypeb
```

Actually there are functions called `ParagraphProcess` and `ParagraphProcessA`.

But how to interpret the prefix(`_Z24ICTCLAS_`) and suffix(`PKciPc9eCodeTypeb`) and the address-like string(`00009634`) at the start of the line?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the -C flag on the nm command? It should demangle the names.